# What is the preferred pattern for re-binding jQuery-style UI interfaces after AJAX load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This always gets me. After initializing all lovely UI elements on a web page, I load some content in (either into a modal or tabs for example) and the newly loaded content does not have the UI elements initialized. eg:

```js
$('a.button').button(); // jquery ui button as an example
$('select').chosen(); // chosen ui as another example
$('#content').load('/uri'); // content is not styled :(
```

My current approach is to create a registry of elements that need binding:

```js
var uiRegistry = {
  registry: [],
  push: function (func) { this.registry.push(func) },
  apply: function (scope) {
    $.each(uiRegistry.registry, function (i, func) {
      func(scope);
    });
  }
};

uiRegistry.push(function (scope) {
  $('a.button', scope).button();
  $('select', scope).chosen();
});

uiRegistry.apply('body'); // content gets styled as per usual

$('#content').load('/uri', function () {
  uiRegistry.apply($(this)); // content gets styled :)
});
```

I can't be the only person with this problem, so are there any better patterns for doing this?

Comment: Your method at least looks better than most, it only targets new elements which is good. I wouldn't have used "apply" as a property name though, that could be confusing.

Comment: Agreed, yours is a good method. That's pretty much what jQuery Mobile does when the `create` event is triggered on a container element, except it uses `data-` attributes instead of classes to match the elements and determine the widgets to use to augment them.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go check out the jQuery Mobile code to see if they're doing anything interesting there.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is basically the same as the one you outline, but I use jquery events to trigger the setup code.  I call it the "moddom" event.

When I load the new content, I trigger my event on the parent:

```
parent.append(newcode).trigger('moddom');
```

In the widget, I look for that event:

```
$.on('moddom', function(ev) {
  $(ev.target).find('.myselector')
})
```

This is oversimplified to illustrate the event method.

In reality, I wrap it in a function domInit, which takes a selector and a callback argument.  It calls the callback whenever a new element that matches the selector is found - with a jquery element as the first argument.

So in my widget code, I can do this:

```
domInit('.myselector', function(myelement) {
  myelement.css('color', 'blue');
})
```

domInit sets data on the element in question "domInit" which is a registry of the functions that have already been applied.

My full domInit function:

```
window.domInit = function(select, once, callback) {
  var apply, done;
  done = false;
  apply = function() {
    var applied, el;
    el = $(this);
    if (once && !done) {
      done = true;
    }
    applied = el.data('domInit') || {};
    if (applied[callback]) {
      return;
    }
    applied[callback] = true;
    el.data('domInit', applied);
    callback(el);
  };
  $(select).each(apply);
  $(document).on('moddom', function(ev) {
    if (done) {
      return;
    }
    $(ev.target).find(select).each(apply);
  });
};
```

Now we just have to remember to trigger the 'moddom' event whenever we make dom changes.

You could simplify this if you don't need the "once" functionality, which is a pretty rare edge case.  It calls the callback only once.  For example if you are going to do something global when any element that matches is found - but it only needs to happen once.  Simplified without done parameter:

```
window.domInit = function(select, callback) {
  var apply;
  apply = function() {
    var applied, el;
    el = $(this);
    applied = el.data('domInit') || {};
    if (applied[callback]) {
      return;
    }
    applied[callback] = true;
    el.data('domInit', applied);
    callback(el);
  };
  $(select).each(apply);
  $(document).on('moddom', function(ev) {
    $(ev.target).find(select).each(apply);
  });
};
```

It seems to me browsers should have a way to receive a callback when the dom changes, but I have never heard of such a thing.

Comment: I'll take a look at this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

best approach will be to wrap all the ui code in a function -even better a separate file -
and on ajax load just specify that function as a call back ..
here is a small example

let's say you have code that bind the text fields with class `someclass-for-date` to a date picker then your code would look like this ..

```
$('.someclass-for-date').datepicker();
```

here is what i think is best

```
function datepickerUi(){
    $('.someclass-for-date').datepicker();
}
```

and here is what the load should look like

```
$('#content').load('/uri', function(){

    datepickerUi();

})
```

or you can load it at the end of your html in script tag .. (but i dont like that , cuz it's harder to debug)

here is some tips

keep your code and css styles as clean as possible .. meaning that for text fields that should be date pickers give them one class all over your website ..
at this rate all of your code will be clean and easy to maintain ..

read more on OOCss this will clear what i mean.

mostly with jquery it's all about organization ... give it some thought and you will get what you want done with one line of code ..

edit

here is a js fiddle with something similar to your but i guess it's a bit cleaner [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mm9Yp/1)